# How do I get all images and videos present in my storage in flutter. Just like a gallery app

Tags: listview, flutter

I am just doing some practice in flutter and don't know how to get URI of all the images and videos present in my storage in flutter.

Here is my code,

```
class Gallery extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_GalleryState createState() => new _GalleryState();
}

class _GalleryState extends State<Gallery> {
List<String> _uriList = new List<String>();


@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
setState((){
  _uriList.add("WHat to enter here??");
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
  title: "Gallery",
  home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Gallery"),
    ),
    body: new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _uriList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){

      },
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: The image_picker plugin should contain the code how to do that https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker

Comment: Are you dealing with storage as in things you downloaded or from assets?

Comment: thanks @GünterZöchbauer, I will try that.